# Accessing XML file in Sitecore Media Library through ASP script

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I have an asp script on a local server where we are also hosting out Sitecore website.

Before we switched to Sitecore, the xml file was sitting in local folder, which was straight forward to access. But now, I am trying to access an xml file in Sitecore Media Library from the asp script and can’t get it to work.

If I type http://localhost/-/media/files/folder/test.xml in IE, it spits out the xml file data from Media Library on Sitecore but for some reason, it won’t work through the script.

```
dim file_location
file_location = "http://localhost/-/media/files/folder/test.xml"

...
getXMLvalue file_location,"date",null,"edt_time"
...

function getXMLValue(strXMLfile, XMLelement, infoID, XMLattrib)

'Declare local variables
Dim objXML, return_value
return_value = null

'Instantiate the XMLDOM Object that will hold the XML file.
set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

'Turn off asyncronous file loading.
objXML.async = false

'Load the XML file.
objXML.load(server.mappath(strXMLFile))

Set objRoot = objXML.documentElement

if XMLelement = "date" then
    set return_value = objRoot.selectSingleNode("date/@" & XMLattrib)

elseif XMLelement = "id" then
    set return_value = objRoot.selectSingleNode("subset/information[@id='" & infoID & "']/" & XMLattrib)

elseif XMLelement = "page_title" then
    set return_value = objRoot.selectSingleNode("page_title")

elseif XMLelement = "date_stamp" then
    set return_value = objRoot.selectSingleNode("date" & XMLvalue)

elseif XMLelement = "timestamp" then
    set return_value = objRoot.selectSingleNode("subset/information/[@id='" & infoID & "']/timestamp/@" & XMLattrib)

end if  

if not(isnull(return_value)) then
    getXMLvalue = return_value.text
end if

'debug use only *****************
'add_to_count
'debug use only *****************

set return_value = nothing
set objRoot = nothing
set objXML = nothing

end function
```

I am trying to read XML file located on Sitecore. This script is located on the same machine as our Sitecore website.

Any suggestions on how to access XML file in Sitecore through ASP script would be helpful?

Comment: `from the asp script` - what is your asp script doing? Reading the file using a TextStream? There is very little technical details in your question, please update it with code snippets. At a guess I would say you are trying to load a file from disk, rather than loading it from a URL.

Comment: HI, I have added some code snippets. I am trying to read XML file located on Sitecore Media Library.

Comment: Why are you doing "objXML.load(server.mappath(strXMLFile))" instead of objXML.load(full url) ?

Comment: objXML.load(full url) didn't work...